# JavaScript change background by entering the color name in the textbox

Tags: javascript

there seems to be some misunderstanding in this code. What is supposed to happen is the input written into one of the text boxes with connect to the button beside. Once a button is pressed either the background of the div or the entire text will be changed. I'm thinking there's some problem with the input box connecting but can't completely figure it out. How can I get the textbox to change the background or text?

```
    <style>
        #main
        {
        background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <!-- <h1></h1> -->

    <input type='text' id='txt1'><button onclick='colour()'>background</button><br>
    <input type='text' id='txt2'><button onclick='text()'>text</button>

    <div id="main">
        <p>
        Phasellus at, condimentum nisl. Sed molestie nec velit euismod convallis. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>        
        var toDiv = document.getElementById('main');

        function colour() 
        {
        var colour2 = document.getElementById('txt1');
        toDiv.style.background = (colour2);
        }

        function text()
        {
        var texting = document.getElementById('txt2');
        main.innerHTML = (texting);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.value` at the end like:

```
 var colour2 = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it works! 

var colour2 = document.getElementById('txt1').value;

Comment: You're welcome. You also spotted my mistake. ThumbsUp +1 for that.